# Is Low German dialect still used in Germany?

Tags: dialect, low-german

I’m curious to know whether Low German dialect is still used in Germany or not.

If so, in which areas? Is it both either spoken and written or only as a colloquial spoken language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Low German dialects are still spoken in northen parts of German, and in eastern parts of the The Netherlands. These dialects are not reflected in everyday writing.

There is a map on Wikipedia depicting regional distributions of Low German dialect variants:

[image] 
<sup>Source: [Wikimedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Niederdeutsche_Dialekte_seit_1945_BRD.PNG)</sup>

There even are [radio and TV shows](https://www.ndr.de/kultur/norddeutsche_sprache/) in Low German (*Platt*). Mostly for documentation, and to preserve the dialect, we may also find written text in Low German. However these text are not officially used.

Comment: Thanks for illustrating map @Takkat ! Is it either as a formal written language in these areas?!

Comment: No it is spoken only... some people do write it down but it is not an officially valid spelling.

Comment: Be warned that not every dialect indicated on the map is still actively used (or even understood) by the average person on the street. In particular, the Westphalian dialects have died out during the last 100 years in most of the orange colored regions of the map.

Comment: It is not so hard to find books written in these dialects. Hence, the dialects are also used in writing.

Comment: @MartinPeters: still, those books are far from "formal written language".

Comment: @Takkat Hm, I disagree. You can find short stories, novel etc.

Comment: _These dialects are not reflected in everyday writing_ Is that true though? What about SMS or messaging services? Don't people write in their dialects there, and aren't those the most representative kinds of everyday writing?

Comment: @sgf actually I don't text with people from Low German dialect regions so I can't say for sure. Nevertheless it would surprise me a lot if people there really wrote their text messages with using their dialect in general (we are not talking about single words or special interest groups). If that is what you experience you should say so in an own answer, best with [giving us examples](https://doi.org/10.15488/3176).

Comment: @Takkat I only know that a surprising amount of people in Austria use their dialect when texting other people from the same region. I know that attitudes towards dialect are different in Germany, but I don't know how different, so I guess it would just surprise me less than you if it turned out to be the case that the same is true for Low German dialects.

Answer (score 9):

The low German dialects, collectively often termed *Plattdeutsch,* have been declining for quite a few centuries but they never became fully extinct. This had to do with the perception of dialect speakers having a lower social status, being from the countryside, enjoying lesser education and all sorts of other prejudices. For some reason, these always affected the North more than it did the South where dialects are more often perceived solely as regiolects and not as sociolects. An anecdotocal case in point is a former colleague of mine whose parents live in a village where occasionally *Platt* is still spoken. She said she understood it but couldn’t speak it herself.

On the other hand, more modernised if you wish versions of Low German dialects are and have been emerging across northern Germany. These dialects are much closer to what is taught as Standard German but still contain marked phonetic and semantic influences of the older *Plattdeutsch* dialects — for example the use of *lütt* instead of *klein* for *small.* These newer dialects have a much stronger speaker base and will probably survive.

In recent years, however, there have been marked efforts to preserve the old *Plattdeutsch* and to teach it to the young generation; including staging theatre performances in *Platt* and more. One of the key players here is the [Ohnsorg-Theater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohnsorg-Theater) in Hamburg, which exclusively stages plays in *Platt*.

---

Concerning the question about written versus spoken: Since the establishment of a more or less common spelling of German, influenced largely but not solely by Luther’s bible translation, written German was always more or less a variant of Standard German and rather far away from most actually spoken dialects. No official writing system for any dialect ever truly existed. However, in all parts of Germany traditional stories such as fairy tales were often told in dialects and thus sometimes written in them as well; one of the most well-known examples of a text written in *Plattdeutsch* is [*Von dem Fischer un syner Fru*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vom_Fischer_und_seiner_Frau) *(Of the Fisherman and his wife).* The late 19th century saw a rise of dialect literature in many parts of the country and though I would know most about the Bavarian examples (see my current avatar) I would be very surprised if there weren’t also marked and well-known (across the North) *Plattdeutsch* examples, too.

The principal difficulty with writing in *Platt* is that every village has their own forms, pronounce at least some word slightly differently such that there is no common codification system in use. Also, some phonemic features of northern German are very hard to codify into writing — arguably, getting the Bavarian *Stoa* or even *Huosi* correct from scratch is much easier than producing something that renders the Hamburg pronunciation of *Stein* well. Official documents have probably not been written in anything *Platt*-like since the fall of the *Hanse.*

---

The areas associated with *Platt* are well shown in the map in [Takkat’s answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/32973). Traditionally, the [Uerdingen line](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uerdinger_Linie) is associated with the border between Low and Central German; ‘Low’ being the northern dialects. The common feature of all of these is the usage of *i(c)k* and related forms for *I* rather than *i(s)ch* (or *i* in the very far South).

[image: Isoglossal line of Uerdingen separating *ik* from *ich*.]

Comment: The https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohnsorg-Theater shows have gained some popularity in the 1970..80ies as they were broadcasted by the NDR (which had ~20% TV market share in the north back then). Especially https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heidi_Kabel playing breezy grannies and https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Vahl playing a shrewd gramps for making the youngsters on the stage do what they want (usually: marry each other/save the family business etc) have become iconic.

Comment: @Janka That was the one I was looking for! Thanks! I remember reading a newspaper article about it (either in the *Zeit* or in the *Süddeutsche)* but I couldn’t find the article in a quick Google search …

Comment: Frisians call their Language Platt, Limburgish etc is called Platt, but that's clearly not Low German. Aren't both terms historically distinct? That it's bad advise to use them synonymously (whereas "Plattdeutsch" maybe an admissible edge case, but I'm not here to compromise). Asking how a prejudice had come about is ill-advised and uncalled for; How old are Friesenwitze? The note about the south is also misguided, Austria is its own state, the Eidgenossen are too south or reclused to be included at all, and the prejudice between Swabi and Franks is stereotypical. Otherwise nice A

Comment: @vectory *Platt* when used to describe languages indeed has two different meanings: the low German dialects *collectively* and, north of a line that goes somewhere through the middle German dialect area, an individual local dialect. The former term is a generalisation and derives from the latter. The distinction in modern German is that *Platt* by itself refers to the low German dialects whereas the individual dialects need a location distinction *(Limburger Platt)* if its not clear from context. (Being in an area whose local dialect is called *Platt* can serve as sufficient context.)

Comment: Frisian, while not being classified as German, still is closely related and many Germans will not know that Frisian isn’t actually a German dialect. So them calling their language *Platt* confirms the rule rather than constitutes an exception.

Comment: @vectory I don’t understand the rest of your comment; why an ‘admissable edge case’? What prejudice? Why are you talking about *Friesenwitze* (I didn’t even hint at them)? What bearing do the Austrian and Swiss states have in the context of this answer? Why is my mention of the South (I guess that’s in the context of *ich* becoming *i* in local dialects?) misguided?